# question involving remainder of complex function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers

The question says -

> Dividing $f(z)$ by $(z-i)$, we get remainder $i$ and dividing by $z+i$, we get remainder $1+i$. Find the remainder upon division of $f(z)$ by $z^2 + 1$

How do I go about approaching this problem?

Comment: One possible way to start is, if $f(z)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}$ , $f(z)=Q_1(z-i)+i$, $Q_1(z)$ is the quotient. And $f(z)=Q_2(z)(z+1)+(1+i)$ , eliminating $z$. We get, and expressing $f(z)$ independently we get, $$f(z)=\frac{Q_1(z)Q_2(z)}{Q_1(z)-Q_2(z)}(1+i)+\frac{Q_1(z)}{Q_1(z)-Q_2(z)}+i$$ And such that, $Q_1(z)$ is perfectly divisible by $Q_1(z)-Q_2(z)$ most probably. To keep f(z) , a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: With the remainder 1+i on division by z+1, f(z) would need to have complex coefficients. Seems unlikely.

Comment: Sorry @Paul by $\mathbb{Z}$ I do mean complex number not integers.

Comment: Write $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ as partial fractions, multiply by $f(z)$ and go from there. I think you get a remainder $\frac{i}{2}(z+2-i)$.

Comment: Since $z^2+1$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, the remainder upon division of $f$ by $z^2+1$ is of the form $az + b$. You need to determine $a$ and $b$. For that, note that since $z\pm i$ divides $z^2+1$, the remainder upon division of $f$ by $z\pm i$ is the remainder upon division of $az+b$ by $z \pm i$.

Answer (score 0):

So you have
$$
\frac{f(z)}{z-i} = i \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{f(z)}{z+i} = 1+i
$$
Then,
$$
i + (1+i) = \frac{f(z)}{z-i} + \frac{f(z)}{z+i}
          = \frac{f(z)}{z^2+1} \left[ (z+i) + (z-i) \right]
          = f(z) \frac{2z}{z^2+1}
$$

Therefore,
$$\frac{f(z)}{z^2+1} = \frac{1+2i}{2z}$$

Comment: Your first line is incorrect. i and 1+i are remainders. Start with partial fractions to put  $$\frac{f(z)}{z^2+1}=\frac{i}{2}(\frac{f(z)}{z+i}-\frac{f(z)}{z-i})$$